# Is it okay to store global clients vector with unsafe when implementing a chat server with async_std?

Tags: rust, rust-async-std

I have implemented a chat server which stores the connected users and if a user send a message, the server echoes it to all other clients.

I have C++ background so I made a global `static mut USERS:Vec<TcpStream>` variable to store and access the users.

I'm handling the connected users from main() like this:

```rust
#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()>{
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:14530").await?;

    loop {
        let (stream, addr) = listener.accept().await?;
        
        unsafe {
            USERS.push(stream.clone());
        }
        
        task::spawn(on_connection(stream, addr));
    }
}
```

and `on_connection` function is:

```rust
async fn on_connection(mut stream:TcpStream, addr:SocketAddr) -> io::Result<()> {
    println!("New Connection: {}", addr.to_string());

    let mut buffer = [0u8; 1024];
    loop {
        let len = stream.read(&mut buffer).await?; 

        if len > 0 {
            print!("Message from {} => {}", addr.to_string(), String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer));
            
            unsafe {
                for mut user in USERS.clone() {
                    user.write(&buffer).await?;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            println!("Disconnected: {}", addr.to_string());
            
            break
        }
    };

    Ok(())
}
```

**Is it okay to use Rust like this?**

I want to make the application safe and use Rust's safe environment without "unsafe". But I couldn't work out how to store global users to access later without unsafe.

Comment: I use DashMap and pass it around to fns that need it

Comment: No, it is not safe. Not sure why `clone()` is used on the vector, but that will not fix the race condition either.

Comment: @J.Doe so should I create a local Vec in `main()` and pass it every function as a parameter?

Comment: Best is probably to use an `Arc<Mutex<Vec<_>>>` and pass it to every function.

Comment: Never, ever, use `static mut`. If you know what you're doing, use `static` with `UnsafeCell`. If you don't (which means "you're not a Rust expert", not "you haven't program in C++"), don't use `unsafe` at all.

Comment: I don't know if async-std is multithreaded: if yes, you probably need `Mutex` (and can leave it as global), if not, you only need to create it in `main()` and pass it downwards.

Comment: As far as I see on `htop` task manager, it spawns as many threads as number of cores. So it is multithreaded I suppose (probably a thread-pool)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comments, this is my "safe version" of the implementation above:

```rust
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use async_std::net::{TcpStream, TcpListener};
use async_std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use async_std::io::{ReadExt, WriteExt, Result};
use async_std::task;


async fn on_connection(mut stream:TcpStream, addr:SocketAddr, users:Arc<Mutex<Vec<TcpStream>>>) -> Result<()> {
    println!("New Connection: {}", addr.to_string());

    let mut buffer = [0u8; 1024];
    loop {
        let len = stream.read(&mut buffer).await?; 

        if len > 0 {
            print!("{} => {}", addr.to_string(), String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer));

            let users = users.lock().await;
            
            for mut user in &*users {
                // send everyone except itself
                if user.peer_addr()? != stream.peer_addr()? {
                    user.write(&buffer).await?;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            println!("Disconnected: {}", addr.to_string());
            break;
        }
    };

    Ok(())
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()>{
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:14530").await?;
    let users = Vec::new();
    let arc_users = Arc::new(Mutex::new(users));
    
    loop {
        let users = arc_users.clone();
        let (stream, addr) = listener.accept().await?;

        let mut write_permission= users.lock().await;
        write_permission.push(stream.clone());
        drop(write_permission);
        
        task::spawn(on_connection(stream, addr, users));
    };
}
```